# Merge table results using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these query results from MenuTable for different User Groups.
A user can have more Groups. So, I want to merge the permissions for all the Groups for same PageID the User belongs to. How can I get this done using SQL Query?

First Result:

```
UserGroupID   PageID   CanView     CanDelete     CanEdit
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1           1         0            0            0
   1           2         1            1            0
   1           3         1            0            0
```

Second Result

```
UserGroupID   PageID   CanView     CanDelete     CanEdit
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   2            1         1            1            1
   2            2         0            0            0
   2            3         0            0            0
```

I want to get this Result.

```
 PageID   CanView     CanDelete     CanEdit
------------------------------------------------------------
   1         1            1            1
   2         1            1            0
   3         1            0            0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple query like this can do :

```
SELECT PageID,
       MAX(CanView)   [CanView],
       MAX(CanDelete) [CanDelete],
       MAX(CanEdit)   [CanEdit]
FROM   table
--WHERE  UserGroupID in(1,2)
GROUP  BY PageID
```

in addition you can use where clause if you want to look in specific groups (commented condition).